# Makefile returning errors

Tags: gcc, makefile, pthreads

I have a makefile that is supposed to compile a set of C files which use the `<pthread.h>` library. Although the makefile ran on my previous Linux installation, I can't get it running now. Can anyone help me with this?

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -std=c99
LDFLAGS= -lpthread
SOURCES=pc_0.c stak.h
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=pcths

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)   
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.c.o:
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f *.o core
```

Here is the error message I get while typing "make" on my shell prompt.

```
gcc pc_0.c -o pc_0.o -c -std=c99
pc_0.c: In function ‘main’:
pc_0.c:25:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)()’
pc_0.c:29:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)()’
pc_0.c:33:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)()’
gcc -lpthread pc_0.o stak.h -o pcths
pc_0.o: In function `main':
pc_0.c:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pc_0.c:(.text+0x15d): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pc_0.c:(.text+0x1ba): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pc_0.c:(.text+0x206): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
pc_0.c:(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
pc_0.c:(.text+0x22e): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pcths] Error 1
```

However, if I manually run the following instructions the sources are compiled:

```
cc pc_0.c -o pc_0.o -c -std=c99
cc pc_0.o -o pcths -lpthread
```

Comment: Can you also post the error it gives?

Comment: That handling of `stak.h` looks wrong. Are you using the same version of gcc on both systems?

Comment: Without the error its just a guess but is libc-dev installed?

Comment: No, I guess the gcc versions are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `-lpthread` at the end of the command line, after the object file, which need symbols from `libthread.[a|so]`

When GNU ld (and other linkers) resolve undefined references it looks for symbol definition only in the object file and libraries, which follow the object, which contains the said references.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how important it is but I always add '' around assignments of variables

Answer (score 0):

Posting the actual error message is of the utmost importance when trying to debug your issue.

Possibly not your issue but I usually set my editor (emacs) to use spaces instead of tabs for indenting and this causes issue in make. I have to highlight all and run `m-x tabify` to fix the issue.